# How to integrate in s-domain

Tags: complex-analysis

We know that a simple integral in the time domain for example, is put like that:

$$\int_a^bf(t)dt$$

So $t$ will vary from $a$ to $b$ and all values in between (like a straight line).
But when I do something like this:

$$\int_{z_1}^{z_2}F(s)ds$$

which I suppose that can be re-written by:

$$\int_{a+jb}^{c+jd}F(s)ds  , s\in \mathbb{C} $$

since $s$ is a complex number. If so, is that the same thing of doing this: (?)

$$\int_{b}^{d}\int_a^cF(p+jq)dpdq$$

If not, what does it really mean to make $s$ vary from a point to another in the complex plane? A straight line connecting both points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To evaluate, or indeed to define, an integral such as $\int_{z_1}^{z_2} F(s) ds$ in the complex domain, a *path* joining $z_1$ and $z_2$ must specified, and for $ds$ to make sense, it must be a *differentiable path*; that is, a map $\gamma:[t_1, t_2] \to \Bbb C$ such that 
$\gamma(t_1) = z_1$ and $\gamma(t_2) = z_2$ and $\gamma'(t)$ exists for all $t \in [t_1, t_2]$.  Then writing $s = \gamma(t)$, we have $ds = \gamma'(t)dt$ and hence

$\int_{z_1}^{z_2} F(s) ds = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} F(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) dt; \tag{1}$

the real and imaginary parts of $ F(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t)$ occurring on the right-hand side of (1) may thus be integrated as ordinary (real) functions of $t$.  Note that we needn't perform a double integral such as $\int_{b}^{d}\int_a^cF(p+jq)dpdq$.  Also, a straight line segment joining $z_1$ and $z_2$ is perhaps the simplest path admissible under the conditions I have stated, and it proves very useful in very many applications; but there are many other possible paths joining $z_1$ and $z_2$; different paths suit different problems.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Nice. It helped a lot. Just one more question: in case of the inverse Laplace transform, is this path implicitly defined?

Comment: @user2110874:  Wow!  you're really forcing me to tap into deep and long-unused memory space here!  It's been awhile since I've been actively involved with Laplace transforms; that, and my lack of knowledge about your specific problem, mean I can only venture a guess, and my guess is "no"; usually you will know $F(s)$ from some linear differential equation, and it will have a set of poles of finite order, so to recover the solution you have to perform a Cauchy residue type integration, and the path's can usually be freely chosen in such a case, though the path must surround . . . (continued)

Comment: surround, though avoid, the singularities of $F(s)$.  As I recall, anyway.  Do you have a more specific example in mind?

Comment: I see...i do not hold anything in mind. My question became because I was thinking of the laplace transform as an algebric tool to solve a diff eq. In those cases, we use the inverse transform to get back our solution in time domain and also there are common definitions (tables) of commonly used transforms. Those proofs usually use the integral in ds and solve it without defining a path from s=0 to +infinity, for example.

Comment: @user2110874:  I see better what you mean; the path goes along the real axis and then loops out into the complex plane; the path *has* to go along the real axis to recover the integral from $0$ to $\infty$.  So in this case I guess it is implicitly defined.  I was thinking at first, when I wrote up my answer, that you were talking about general complex integration, not Laplace transforms where a Cauchy integral is used to evaluate something along the real axis etc.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the general case but also that integral came into my mind. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @user2110874:  glad I could help out, and thanks for the "acceptance"! ;-)